# Observing Properties with Custom Accessors

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing

Let's say I want to observe the `hidden` property on UIView:

`@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden`

Do I add an observer for the keypath **`hidden`** or **`isHidden`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hidden`.

Think about it from the other side: setting the property. The setter will be `setHidden:`, not `setIsHidden:`, and your property assignments will be `self.hidden = flag`, not `self.isHidden = flag`.